# Sync complains about not unique Attiribute

Tags: azure-active-directory

[image]

AAD complains about errors in the sync process.

But I don't understand what the duplicate is there.
Already tried a full import, delta import, full sync etc.

How do I find the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

There are three attributes mainly checked during azure ad connect: userPrincipalName, proxyAddresses, and sourceAnchor/immutableID in [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant#sync-with-existing-users-in-azure-ad).
You can make use of [IDFix](https://microsoft.github.io/idfix/Step%203%20-%20Query%20and%20fix%20invalid%20attributes/) tool to identify the duplicate objects.

Please Check below scenarios if they are the cause:

1. If you/ User is  Global Admin
   Try to remove the role and sync the user without admin role or by adding user role.After the sync  then you can  add the role again.

Or
If it is already in sync ,Disable the directory sync process ,then delete the user
from domain (on-prem directory) and then do the azure ad sync and then add the
user role to admin  back if required.

2. During Azure ad connect , we must take care of SMTP Soft match and ImmutableID hardmatch. [soft-vs-hard-match](https://www.itpromentor.com/soft-vs-hard-match/)

```js
    $credential = Get-Credential
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
    $ADUser = "username" 
    $AzureADUser = "username@emaildomainname.com"
    $guid =(Get-ADUser $ADUser).Objectguid
    $immutableID=[system.convert]::ToBase64String($guid.tobytearray())
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "$AzureADUser " -ImmutableId $immutableID
```

This can take care of mismatch .See [error-type-attributevaluemustbeunique](https://www.steijvers.com/2021/05/27/error-type-attributevaluemustbeunique/)  & [this](https://tom-bullock.com/2021/01/14/ad-connect-attributevaluemustbeunique/)

Note : Please do resync after any changes.

**Other references:**

1. [Azure AD Sync, duplicate user - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/879990/azure-ad-sync-duplicate-user)
2. [Troubleshoot directory synchronization errors  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/active-directory/duplicate-attributes-prevent-dirsync#cause)
3. [diagnose sync errors (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-health-diagnose-sync-errors.md)
4. [AAD connect design concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-design-concepts)

Comment: On option 1 you mean the user who is used for the sync?

Comment: Ya, check for  the user or users if he is admin   who is having sync error

Comment: I ran the idfix took and it showed me that the upansuffix '@mycompany.local' has a proplem and is not routable. I fixed that by changing the suffix to '@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com' and the errror is gone in the idfix tool. 
But it remains in the azure sync, but azure has recognized the new suffix.

Comment: Have you tried to resync again by diabling sync and then enabling ?

Comment: yes, I have tried this.